# Change in HTML snippet in Spring '17 causing integration failure

Tags: integration, html, release

We have an integration where we use the HTML elements from our salesforce org. The image source path seems to have changed in Spring 17 which is breaking our integration.

Replication - Login to Salesforce org >> Inspect>> Elements. The img src in Winter '17 used to be /s.gif where as in Spring '17 org it has become /img/s.gif

Is there any way we can skill keep using /s.gif.

PS: Screenshots attached.
[image: Image depicts behavior in Spring '17 and Winter 17]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those unfortunate things that happen when you depend on internal resources, including images, styles, JavaScript, or other internal HTML structures within Salesforce. Salesforce.com has never explicitly stated that we *should* depend on s.gif being an available resource. I think it's probably unfortunate that they decided to make this change without notifying customers, because I'm pretty sure you're not the only one that was using this 1x1 image.

If you need this image for most practical purposes, you can use a data-uri instead:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

This URL will work with CSS, img src attributes, and other places you might ordinarily need a spacer image. For example, as an image:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
```

As a background image:

```
background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sfdcfox , you are right, it may be reported by more users in the coming days specially when production organizations are upgraded to Spring '17.